# Can we upload data on custom object owned by a managed package

Tags: managed-package, data-loader

We installed a managed package called object converter. It is using a custom object and we want to do a data load using data loader. If we try to edit a record or update any data on the custom object, it is complaining on permissions not allowed to update or insert in custom object. How can we edit or insert records into custom objects owned by managed package?
Buyan

Comment: Have you got the right assignments set up via Manage Licenses?

Answer (score 2):

Permissions on custom objects work the same with managed packages with the one addition user320 mentions - if the package is licensed per user, the user executing the update must have a licence for the package. Is there a Manage Licences link next to the package name in Installed Packages? If so, the package requires licences to be allocated to individual users.

Comment: We dont have a license yet for this managed package and is a trial version. How can we find out what permissions we have on that custom object? I am using system admin profile and yet i cannot edit data.

Comment: When you go to Installed Packages, is there a Manage Licences link? If not, they you should have a site licence, and be able to access it with normal permissions...if yes, ask the vendor for a licence